# How to create unit test if result is logging with NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, nslog

I want to create unit test that check one particular case. Result of this case is logging with system function `NSLog`.

```
<2014-02-19 03:05:11> Warning bla-bla-bla. Please, check you code.
```

I've searched a lot, but have not found a decent solution. Is there any chance that logging operation can be captured through observation or mb Xcode console content can be retrieved in some way?

Any advice will be helpful!

**EDIT** Alright, I see there's some misunderstanding what I want to test. The library want to warn developer, who uses it, about some bad input. It will continue to process them anyway and will return result(mb incorrect result). But at some point of processing I check value(not initial value though) and log warning message and, then, continue to process. Even if I encapsulate this logic I don't want to have this functionality public.

Comment: Change your code to make it more testable...

Comment: @Immi, I checked the article and don't see how it can help me

Comment: @Wain, Making this snippet more testable is related with adding more overhead for this feature. As library developer, I want to avoid it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same case , so what you can do is 
1.Direct your log to a txt file.

```
+ (void)recordLog{
    NSArray *allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [allPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    pathForLog = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FWTestLog.txt"];
    NSLog(@"path = %@",pathForLog);

    stderrSave = dup(STDERR_FILENO);
    freopen([pathForLog cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
}
```

2.Search a the string "bla-bla-bla" pattern in the txt file.And use XCTTest to test if the string is found.

3.Close the file and delete it so the other nslog will go back to console.

```
+ (void)closeLog{
    fflush(stderr);
    dup2(stderrSave,STDERR_FILENO);
    close(stderrSave);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:pathForLog error:&error];
}
```

I wrap it inside my custom test class so that I can use it with other standard XCTTest

Comment: I had a similar issue like op where I wanted to test that the log has a specific warning for the developer using my library.
I tried this solution and it only recorded stuff logged from within the test target (e.g. if I logged something from a test case). 
Anything else was not in that log. Maybe now 6 years later things behave differently and this solution is out of date?

Answer (score 2):

You don't show any code, but it sounds like you want to test the value of a string that, during runtime, is only appearing in the log.  You can easily isolate this method to allow unit-testing to work.

So imagine the current code is:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    NSString *string = @"Generated using some process";
    NSLog(@"String is %@", string);
    [self useString:string];
}
```

This can be changed to:

```
- (NSString *)generateString {
    NSString *string = @"Generated using some process";
    return string;
}

- (void)someMethod {
    NSString *string = [self generateString];
    NSLog(@"String is %@", string);
    [self useString:string];
}
```

Your unit-test will then focus on `generateString` rather than `someMethod`.

Comment: I don't post any code because I want to see approach that does not use it=) Anyway, in this case I want to keep this method private, because it does not bring any benefits to an user(another developer)

Comment: @Ossir You can still keep it private.  Conventionally (for me, anyway) private methods are prefixed with underscore.  As long as it doesn't appear in the header then it can be considered private, and can still be called, but you will most likely need some `#pragma`s in your unit-test code to quieten-down `clang`.

Comment: I'm wondering can we reach 100% unit test coverage with such approach

Comment: @Ossir Well this approach doesn't change the coverage potential of your unit tests, it just breaks the units being tested into smaller pieces.  In a UI program I don't see any easy way to achieve 100% coverage, but I haven't investigated exhaustively.

Comment: No one talks about UI app. With such approach you checking only this method, but not the code that perform it, I don't see the way how to check this code too.

Comment: @Ossir I cannot suggest an approach as I don't know what it does.  If it does something that is recorded in some way (for example instance variable being modified) then the test would be to test for this change to the instance variable.  If it writes to a file, then you could check the file's modified time and/or size.  I don't think it's possible to get 100% coverage without making the code so complicated that it becomes unmaintainable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a conversion to Swift, I also added the search function:

```
class YourTestClass: XCTestCase {

    // Used class properties here, because only a specific output is put to the logfile, rest of the logs shall stay in the console e.g. for your build server logs.
    var stderrSave: Int32 = 0
    var logFilePath: String {
        get {
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
            return documentsPath! + "/FWTestLog.txt"
        }
    }

    // Will be called before you want to have all logs being redirected to your logile
    func startLogging() {
        self.stderrSave = dup(STDERR_FILENO)
        freopen(self.logFilePath.cString(using: .ascii), "a+", stderr)
    }

    // Will be called when you want to stop redirecting all logs to a separate file
    func closeLogging() {
        fflush(stderr);
        dup2(stderrSave,STDERR_FILENO);
        close(stderrSave);
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: self.logFilePath)
    }

    // Search for the according string
    func recordLog(logged string:String) -> Bool {
        let content = try? String(contentsOfFile: self.logFilePath)
        return (content?.hasSuffix(string + "\n"))!
    }

    func testExample() {
        self.startLogging()
        var isRecorded = self.recordLog(logged: "your logged string")
        XCTAssertFalse(isRecorded, " String should not have been logged yet: \"your logged string\"")
        NSLog("your logged string")
        isRecorded = self.recordLog(logged: "your logged string")
        self.closeLogging()
        XCTAssertTrue(isRecorded, " Expected the String to be logged: \"your logged string\"")
    }
}
```